# how to fix check dependencies error in xcode?

Tags: swift

How do you fix check dependencies error in xcode? error is below:

Check dependencies

“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

Answer (score 0):

If that’s the error, you need to manually select the swift version, and convert if required:

Manual swift version selection:

> Project ► (Select Your Project Target) ► Build Settings ► (Type
>   'swift' in Searchbar) Swift Compiler Language ► Swift Language Version
>   ► Click on Language list to open it.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Doing so resulted in more errors, and the same error persisted.

Comment: Can I please send you my project on your patreon?